# Flutter/ How to pass and get data between Statefulwidget

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm a junior (or less than, just 1 month learner) dart/flutter developer.
I try to create an sample proflie applicaiton that 
- Show user's profile image on the main screen. 
- User can use in-app camera to take photo or select from album and show as personal profile pic.

I have create 2 main viewController.

1. main.dart

   ```
   void main() {
    runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
     '/screen1': (BuildContext context) => new MyApp(),
     '/screen3': (BuildContext context) => new UploadAvatarButton()
     },
    ));
   }

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
     final String _images =  "";
     MyApp(String _images, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
     @override
     State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
      return new MyHomePage();
     }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends State<MyApp> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget myPhoto = new Container(
    //Attribute
    child: new FlatButton(
     child: new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
       shape: BoxShape.circle,
       image: new DecorationImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover, image: new AssetImage('images/sample.jpg')),
       ),
      ),
    onPressed: _showPersBottomSheetCallBack,
     ),
    );

    return new MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
    //Header
    body: new Center(
     child: new Column(
       crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
       children: [
         new Container(child: myPhoto),
   ```

and 2. cameraView.dart

```
class UploadAvatarButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new MakeUploadAvatarButtonState();
  }
class MakeUploadAvatarButtonState extends State<UploadAvatarButton> {
  File _image;
  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
//Try to send data or image back to main screen
      List<int> imageBytes = image.readAsBytesSync();
      String base64Image = BASE64.encode(imageBytes);
//send data back
      Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => 
  new MyApp(_image.)));
    });
  }
```

As you can see, I use method to send image back
From camera

```
List<int> imageBytes = image.readAsBytesSync();
  String base64Image = BASE64.encode(imageBytes);
  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => 
  new MyApp(_image.)));
```

in to main

```
final String _images =  "";
MyApp(String _images, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
```

However, I got the error

```
[dart] The constructor returns type 'dynamic' that isn't of expected type 'Widget'.
```

Could you please advise me?

Best regards
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Modify the constructor as

> MyApp(this._images)

to access the image in the MyHomePage class

> widget._images

Comment: Thanks it works now, sorry for reply late.