# passing data from the login screen to the home page. the data is received from an api that returns user data if the login data is correct

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm returning user data and a token if the login data is correct. i want to pass the user data from the login page to other screens and use it within the app.

Below is the data i want to send to other screens...

```
data: {key: 4fd863897407cdf68e0ee073fcf08f7224d8aa25, user: {id: 2, first_name: Lina, last_name: Jorevaa, username: lina, email: lina@gmail.com, is_super_doc: false, is_doc: true}}
```

my mobile app ui is built with flutter while my rest api is built with django rest framework and rest-auth

```
*my login.dart*

Future<List> loginData() async {
    final response = await http
        .post('http://192.xxx.xxx.xxxx:42366/api/v1/rest-auth/login/', headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }, body: {
      'email': '${emailController.text.trim().toLowerCase()}',
      'password': '${passwordController.text}'
    });

    setState(() {
      status = response.body.contains('error');
      data = json.decode(response.body);
      if (status) {
        setState(() {
          _showDialog();
        });
        print('data: ${data['error']}');
      } else {
        print('data: $data');
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => HomeScreen(
                  list: data,
                  index: 1,
                ),
          ),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
        );
      }
    });
    return data;
  }
```

```
*my home.dart*
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List list;
  final int index;

  HomeScreen({this.list, this.index});
```

This is the error i am getting

Unhandled Exception: type `'_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>'` is not a subtype of type `'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>'`

Expecting clarification

Comment: the error... '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>'

Answer (score 0):

This error makes sense because the function you've defined is of type Future. So, you should be returning a variable of same type i.e. `Future<List>`. Over here, 'data' is `Map<String, dynamic>`.

If you change the function type to `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>`, you'll be successfully returning the data from function `loginData()`.

To pass data from one screen to other, you will have to define the class property in the destination class. And use it while calling the screen. Example [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861302/passing-data-between-screens-in-flutter).