# How to share provider data from streambuilder via different pages (contextes)

Tags: firebase, flutter

I want to have data from firebase in realtime on a widget. When I try to use a `StreamProvider` and then use `Navigator.push()`, the pushed widget can't get the value with `Provider.of(context)`.

I tried putting the `StreamProvider` as the parent of `MaterialApp`. This works but the user needs to be logged in order for the Stream to get the data of the user. 
I also tried using a `ScopedModel`. This works as well, but I don't know if this is the best approach to do this.

I would like to avoid using a global `StreamProvider` and would like to have an efficient solution (as little reads from firebase as possible)

`main.dart`

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> mainScaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> authScaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel<ScreenModel>(
      model: ScreenModel(),
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<User>.value(value: authService.userDoc,),
          StreamProvider<bool>.value(value: authService.loading.asBroadcastStream())
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: "ListAssist",
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
          ),
          home: MainApp()
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    bool loading = Provider.of<bool>(context);

    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      child: user != null ?
        StreamProvider<Group>.value(
          value: databaseService.streamGroupsFromUser(),
          child: Scaffold(
            key: mainScaffoldKey,
            body: Body(),
            drawer: Sidebar(),
          ),
        ) : Scaffold(
       key: authScaffoldKey,
       body: AnimatedSwitcher(
         duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
         child: loading ? SpinKitDoubleBounce(color: Colors.blueAccent) : AuthenticationPage(),
       ),
       resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
     )
    );
  }
}
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  createState() => _Body();
}

class _Body extends State<Body> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModelDescendant<ScreenModel>(
      builder: (context, child, model) => model.screen
    );
  }
}
```

In the Sidebar I can change to `GroupView` and the `Provider` still works.

`sidebar.dart` (important part)

```dart
onTap: () {
  ScreenModel.of(context).setScreen(GroupView(), "Gruppen");
  Navigator.pop(context);
},
```

The `GroupView` has `GroupItem` in it

`group-item.dart` (important part)

```dart
onTap: () => Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    return GroupDetail();
  }),
)
```

When I try to use `Group group = Provider.of<Group>(context);` in `GroupDetail` or a child widget of it, it says that it cannot find any `Provider` for the `context`.

Here is the [repository](https://github.com/ListAssist/listassist-app/tree/testgruppen).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general it is better to include the code directly in the question rather than link to the repository

Comment: I think the reason provider.of(context) doesn't work after using navigator.push() is because you are pushing to a new context, and the new context isn't nested under the provider widget.

Comment: One option is to save the user information as some kind of object and then passing it to the new context as a parameter in the constructor of the new page. Or re-listening to the stream from the new context.

Comment: I tried using parameters for the new Widget, however, then the data is not in realtime anymore. I don't really want to do it with re-listening, because everytime the widget gets opened it will read from Firebase again, and I would like to keep the reads minimal.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: From my point of view it's more of a design question than a code questiion @FrankvanPuffelen, so please don't just post links instead of answering the answer

Comment: I would probably go with the screen model approach. As long as it works keep going with it until it doesn't work.

Comment: in the code example StreamProvider is a parent of MaterialApp isnt it? Or do one need to wrap MaterialApp in a Builder() widget?

Comment: Yes. User should be global. Something like groups should be loaded first when the user presses on the groups button in der sidebar. This works but if you do an navigator.push afterwards you loose the provider. That's the problem :-/ @Marc

Comment: cant tell you why this is the case. To me the context of where the Providers are set are above the MaterialApp Widget, where the navigator is created. Perhaps you should look at the widgetsTree after you did the push on the navigator. And did you try wrapping the MaterialApp in a Builder() ?

Comment: Yes. It works if you put the Provider ABOVE the MaterialApp() since its context doesn't change. That's the thing. But putting it in a global context is not really nice nor perfomant. @Marc

Comment: cant see a problem putting it above. Do it always this way.

Comment: Then the API / firestore db gets called even if the user won't go to the group section... @Marc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. I used a package called `custom_navigator`.

In `sidebar.dart` I changed the child when someone changes to the group view to the following:

```dart
StreamProvider<Group>.value(
  value: databaseService.streamGroupsFromUser(user.uid),
  child: CustomNavigator(
    home: GroupView(),
    pageRoute: PageRoutes.materialPageRoute,
  )
)
```

With the `CustomNavigator` I can still use `Provider.of<Group>(context)` to get the data, even after a `Navigator.push()`.

Comment: Nice and efficient solution +1

Comment: Perfect answer and question, followed all Stackoverflow guidlines