# Sending data to the new Screen in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/placebids', arguments: {
  'ProductId': productDocumentId,
  'ProductName': productName,
});
```

I am passing this data to the new screen in flutter and i have to use it in the initState() method. Can anyone help how to do this.

Comment: this will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861302/passing-data-between-screens-in-flutter

Comment: I have applied this technique but when i am using those values in the initState i am getting error

Comment: can you please provide your full code

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can get back the data by using in the new screen:

```dart
final Map arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;
```

Then you will be able to get the productId by using:

```dart
arguments['ProductId']
```

It's the solution for recovering data, the way you pass it on.

Alternatively you can also use state management tools like MobX, Provider, ... which will allow you to simplify the sharing of variables between screens.