# Flutter : How to refresh screen when user come back to it from any other screen

Tags: flutter, dart

### For ex.

I am on Screen-1 , **push** screen and goto Screen-2.
and then I **replace** Screen-2 with Screen-3 
and now I **pop** that Screen-3 with **pass some data** 
and come back to Screen-1
and I want refresh data in Screen-1

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `Provider`?

Comment: I use it in past but after update flutter sdk there is some problem in provider lib that's why i dont want to use

Comment: you dont have to do anything - "Screen 1"'s `build` method is called so the first screen is updated

Comment: @pskink I think he wants to pass data from `Screen3` to `Screen1`

Comment: @CopsOnRoad so let him say it... but, yes, in 50% you may be right

Comment: He just wants to refresh screen 1 coming back from Screen 3 (Screen 2 is replaced by Screen 3) @CopsOnRoad

Comment: @pskink Haha, let's see.

Comment: @VinothVino In that case pskink is right.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad   Yes i want to pass data from screen-3 and then refresh screen-1 according to that data

Comment: check https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments and https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

Comment: See this answer for passing data back to the previous screen. @Sanjayrajsinh https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861303/4608334

Comment: Thank you everyone give me great response  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this (but you must go from 3 to 2 and finally 1) to get some value then refresh it:

```
var result = await Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2()));
        if (result != null) {
          setState(() {
            valueYouChangeIt = result;
          });
        }
```

And then send this value back from Screen2 with:

```
_sendDataBack(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pop(context, valueToSendBack);
  }
```

Or if you want to refresh everything you can write _initState function where you initialize your data and then call _initState on result.

Said that, all this can be super tedious process, so if it's a small app with 2 to 5 screens it can be ok, but with more screens, like someone else commented, I'd prefer to use Provider.

Comment: This would make your UX look ugly.

Comment: well I'm not recommending it but I have an app in production that use this approach and it works just fine, but I'm refactoring everything implementing provider, because there is too much code there and is too dificult to read even for me...