# flutter passing multiple data with getx

Tags: flutter, get, arguments, send, flutter-getx

I want to Pass multiple data from one screen to another screen with Get package.

```
Get.to(Second(), arguments: ["First data", "Second data"]);
```

Answer (score 36):

**Step: 1** : Sending data

```
Get.to(Second(), arguments: ["First data", "Second data"]);
```

**Step: 2** : Get data From first screen

```
var data = Get.arguments;
```

Comment: I am passing data like: `onPressed: () => Get.to(() => GendersPage(),
                      arguments: {"FOR_SELECTION", true})`, but when I try to access argument as map, I get an error. `final Map<String, bool>? args = Get.arguments;
  bool get forSelection => args!["FOR_SELECTION"]!;`

Comment: Is there a way to use onGenerateRoute function, like in the documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments, but using getx?

Answer (score 35):

If you need to pass data with **key** and **value** in **getx** then try this

**First Screen**

```
Get.to(() => SecondScreen(), arguments: [
    {"first": 'First data'},
    {"second": 'Second data'}
]);
```

**Second screen**

```
class SecondScreenController extends GetxController {
  dynamic argumentData = Get.arguments;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    print(argumentData[0]['first']);
    print(argumentData[1]['second']);
    super.onInit();
  }
}
```

**Get.back() result**

```
Get.to(() => SecondScreen(), arguments: [
   {"first": 'First data'},
   {"second": 'Second data'}
]).then((result) {
    if (result[0]["backValue"] == "one") {
        print("Result is coming");
    }
});

Get.back(result: [
    {"backValue": "one"}
]);
```

Comment: What about the case of ''Get.back();'' To send data back? Any ideas? I'm struggling with it hardly

Comment: @carrasc0 I edited the answer please check.

Answer (score 18):

I found this solution.

**First screen**

```dart
Get.to(Second(), arguments: ["First data", "Second data"]);
```

**Second screen**

Declare variable (list)

```dart
var one = Get.arguments;
```

Set data

```dart
Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text("${one[0]}"), // first element set here
          Text("${one[1]}"), // second element set here
        ],
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass  a String, a Map, a List, or even a class instance.

```
Get.toNamed("/example_page", arguments: {'arg1': 'val1', 'arg2': 'val2'};
```

On the next page:

```
final args = Get.arguments;
print(args); // output: {arg1:val1, arg2:val2}
```

[More detail](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md#send-data-to-named-routes)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to  pass data on any List/ ModelClass in Getx arguments,

first Screen

```
     List<ModelClassName>modelList = [];
```

Navigation

```
  Get.toNamed(YouRoutes.Name ,
                        arguments:  modelList[index] );
```

note - "index" in under ListView.builder.

Next Screen

```
ModelClassName data = Get.arguments;
```