# I need to pass data from a widget to a new widget not screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter

As per image I want to push the data into a new widget...

[image]

In the second widget I have creator a constructor:

`final Unint8List image`
create the new container
`Container(child: Image.Memory(widget.image)`

eerything is fine but from the first container I need to push the Image into the second container....
using:

`Navigator.push...... SecondWidget(image: image)` it doesnt work, which kind of Navigator I need to use??

Comment: Please see that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861302/passing-data-between-screens-in-flutter). There its explained in detail.

Comment: `navigator` is used for redirecting to some other page. in your pic it looks same page so use `setState()` and just set the variable to you like

Comment: you do not need to navigate or pass the data, it looks like you are in the same page, so you can use setState but be sure to use a stateful widget and in this way.

Comment: I am trying to pass the data with setState but nothing happen... I am using:
```setstate() {
NewWidget(image: uploadedImage)
}```