# how to pass value of onTap() from a page to another dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to store a value from onTap() into a variable to use it in another page

```
onTap: () {
                    getCourseName(doc["Course name"]);
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      PageTransition(
                        type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
                        child: XDSections(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
```

this code was used in page Courses
I want to use this value in a way to use it page Section

how do i do that ?

Comment: Can you explain more your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use (arguments) parameter in Navigator.push() in order to pass data from one page to another.
Example:

```
              Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => XDSections(),
                    settings: RouteSettings(
                      arguments: "Passed Data",
                    ),
                  ),
                );
```

and for receiving it on XDSections Build Widget:

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
```

More info on [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

also it's answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861302/passing-data-between-screens-in-flutter) in more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the course name as an argument while navigating to you next screen.

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    PageTransition(
        type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft,
        child: XDSections(),
    ),
    arguments: {'courseName': "PASS_YOUR_VALUE_HERE"}
);
```

On your next screen you can get that value by following:

`var arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;`