# Indexing GridView in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm new to flutter and i'm using GridViews for the first time.
Is there a way I can use indexes on this GridView so each element can take to a separate page?
as the code shows, all of the items take to the same page since I added the InkWell.
(items are defined above the following code)

here is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Items> myList = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6];
    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 18,
          mainAxisSpacing: 18,
          children: myList.map((data) {
            return InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => PlaceHolderWidgetDoctor()));
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      data.img,
                      width: 42,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 14,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      data.title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      data.subtitle,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white38,
                          fontSize: 10,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 14,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      data.event,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white70,
                          fontSize: 11,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList()),
    );
  }
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> [Passing data between screens in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861302/passing-data-between-screens-in-flutter)

As seen in the link, it does not send the list element when entering the new page.

Inside the PlaceHolderWidgetDoctor page must have an expected items value

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => PlaceHolderWidgetDoctor(item: data)));
```

You can create the page by capturing the data variable in the PlaceHolderWidgetDoctor page

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I fixed it by adding a separate path into the parent class of the grid item, solved the issue!