# How to return value when navigator to another page in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a code like this:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<String>(builder: (context) => bolatAktar_bolatAktar_filtrelemeSonucu()));
```

When going to the `bolatAktar_bolatTransfer_filterlemeResult()` page, I want to import data that I can use on that page. I will send a total of 2 data. One is double and the other is String type data. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can check this answer for a details explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861303/8626811

Comment: try this https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
String? value = await Navigator.push<String>(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute<String>(
    builder: (context) => bolatAktar_bolatAktar_filtrelemeSonucu(
      d: 0.0,
      s: ""
    )
  )
);
```