# How to encode the passed data to JSON in the form in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, variables, screen, global, local

I have passed the data in a variable of the previous screen to the next using the guidance of the chosen answer in this post: [Passing data between screens in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861302/passing-data-between-screens-in-flutter)

That variable should be encoded into JSON along with the data gathered from the form in this screen, but it is not identified there.
What is going on here? I thought a variable declared inside the global class was identified within it.
Thank you for any guidance you can give me. The code is as follows:

```
    import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class CustomerForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final String askLoan;
  const CustomerForm({Key key, @required this.askLoan}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  CustomerFormState createState() {
    return CustomerFormState();
  }
}
final branchList = ['අගලවත්ත', 'ආගරපතන', 'යක්කලමුල්ල', 'යටියන්තොට'];


class CustomerFormState extends State<CustomerForm> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _name = '';
  String _age = '';
  String _nic = '';
  String _sex = '';
  String _telephone = '';
  String _address = '';
  String _email = '';
  String _inquiry = '';
  String _branch = '';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'ඔබේ තොරතුරු පහත පුරවන්න',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: (20.0),
              ),
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            shadowColor: Colors.tealAccent[50]),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: Column(children: [
.............
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_sex.isNotEmpty &&
                      _branch.isNotEmpty &&
                      formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    formKey.currentState.save();
                    final message = '$_name, විමසීම සාර්ථකයි.';
                    final snackBar = SnackBar(
                      content: Text(message),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
                    );
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                    return http.post(
                        Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/userdata'),
                        headers: <String, String>{
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                        },
                        body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
                          'name': _name,
                          'age': _age,
                          'NIC': _nic,
                          'sex': _sex,
                          'tel': _telephone,
                          'addr': _address,
                          'email': _email,
                          'inquiry': _inquiry,
                          'branch': _branch,
                          'askloan': askLoan,
                        }));
                  } else {
                    final message =
                        'කරුණාකර සියළු තොරතුරු සපයා ඇතිදැයි යළි පරීක්ෂා කරන්න.';
                    final snackBar = SnackBar(
                      content: Text(message),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 4000),
                    );
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                  }
                },
                child: Text('ඔබේ විමසීම මෙතැනින් අප වෙත යොමුකරන්න.'),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 25),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where have you used askLoan again in your code?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I have removed it since it doesn't work, it is with http.post body JSON encode.  In the IDE it says 'Undefined name: askLoan'. I edited the question with the code in it. Please find, and sorry again.