# how to pass search delegate selected result to next page flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, search

I am new to flutter i got stuck on this i dont know what to do please help.
I have a searchdelegate search page I want to click on the results to view the full view details in next page. I used PHP as backend and json data into dart **DataList** view class here i imported the DATALIST.dart and api_service.dart to search in the json api to fetch data what i wanted. here i only search for names when i click on the names to show the full details in next page. all the data are from the json api.

i hope you undertand what i want to do.

```
import 'package:vms_1/DATALIST.dart';
import 'package:vms_1/Handout.dart';

import 'api_service.dart';

class SearchUser extends SearchDelegate {
  FetchUserList _Datalist = FetchUserList();

  @override
  ThemeData appBarTheme(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return theme.copyWith(
      primaryColor: theme.backgroundColor,
      primaryIconTheme: theme.iconTheme,
      primaryColorBrightness: theme.primaryColorBrightness,
      primaryTextTheme: theme.primaryTextTheme,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            query = '';
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.close))
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: const LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [
              Colors.deepPurple,
              Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ]),
      ),
      child: FutureBuilder<List<Datalist>>(
          future: _Datalist.getDatalist(query: query),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            List<Datalist>? data = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data?.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final emp = data![index];
                  return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Card(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      elevation: 2.0,
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text('${data?[index].name}'),
                        subtitle: Text('${data?[index].email}'),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                            new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) => new handout(),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              colors: [
                Colors.deepPurple,
                Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              ]),
        ),
        child: FutureBuilder<List<Datalist>>(
            future: _Datalist.getDatalist(query: query),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              List<Datalist>? data = snapshot.data;
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: data?.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final emp = data![index];
                    return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Card(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                        elevation: 2.0,
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text('${data?[index].name}'),
                          subtitle: Text('${data?[index].email}'),
                          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                          onTap: () { },
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  });
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here I want to show the selected item to be shown on handout page
how to pass data to the next page to show the employee full details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You possibly want to [Pass arguments to a named route](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments) , also have a look at e.g. [Passing data between screens in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861302/passing-data-between-screens-in-flutter) - hope that helps.