# Get the id of a firestore document in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

after following the flutter documentation code to [send data to a new screen](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data), I want to retrieve the firestore id of the todo instance in the detail screen. is there a way to do that?
this is the detail screen:

```
  const DetailScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final todo = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Todo;

    // Use the Todo to create the UI.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(todo.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text(todo.description),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you recently stored the todo instance in firestore? If not there is no firestore ID yet - you can assign your own or have one automatically generated. If the todo instance is stored but you don't have the ID, you may need to use a query on some other properties to find the instance again.

Comment: @Chris the instance is stored in firestore and has an automatically generated id. I guess I could query on all the properties to find a particular instance. However, I don't know if it's a good practice if the document has so many fields.

Answer (score 0):

When storing or reading the item(s) from the database you should keep the handle of the document ID. Then, when you move to the detail page you can do a firebase lookup on the document ID of the `todo` instance like so:

```
final docRef = db.collection("myCollection").doc(todoId);
docRef.get().then(
  (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    // ...
  },
  onError: (e) => print("Error getting document: $e"),
);
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861302/passing-data-between-screens-in-flutter) covers sending data between flutter screens. See the [Firebase docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
var todoId = await db.collection("todoCollection").doc(todoId).id;
```