# Accesing data from another page in Flutter

Tags: flutter

how can I acces data from another screen in flutter.
[I want to use randomName to another page, how can I do that?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7GTC.png)

Comment: We need a lot more information to be able to help you here. First, make it easier for us and post your code as code sample in your question and add some more information. From your discription, for example, we have no idea how you set up your routing for your different pages, which in this case is very critical information.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

You can check the official docs to learn how to pass data between screens.

Also attaching link to a Stack Overflow page for further reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53861302/passing-data-between-screens-in-flutter