# How to navigate with tabs

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to navigate from the 'Home' page (left) to 'Show All' page (right) in my flutter project using the 'show all' button (green arrow).

When the Men/Women/Kids tab is selected in the 'Home' page the same tab should be selected in the 'Show All' page, displaying products from that tab.

[image: Two side-by-side screenshots of a mobile shopping application for shoes. The left screenshot is of the Home view, and the right is of the Show All view.]

Answer (score 0):

#### The easy way:

All you need to work with tabs is in this demo: [Work with tabs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/tabs)

#### The Harder way:

Create your own **Buttons** for tab navigation, and set manually each action to replace the content of your app. This way you can have custom transitions, animations, etc...

#### About navigation:

Notice that you can create any sort of page navigation.
You can either create a full page, but notice it will be drawn over the current page where you've called the action:

```dart
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourScreen()),
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two options

1. Pass the current tab value to the Show All page when you call `Navigator.push()` (or equivalent). [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861303/9063935); [example2](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data).

   This has the benefit of being very simple and quick to implement, but with the downside that if you then change tab inside the 'Show All' page it won't synchronise with the 'Home' page if you navigate back.
2. Store the currently selected tab somewhere 'above' those two pages in the widget tree, so they can both reference it as shared state. [Example 1](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#lifting-state-up)

   This has the benefit of synchronising the two pages, but is a little more complex.