# Pass data between advanced pages (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, methods, widget

its me again. Hope you can help please. Im working advanced UI programming so I have this view divided into two parts:

[CodeView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImtoC.png)

The first one its named **create_order_page.dart**, in this file at the **CreateCQpart1**,  I have on TextFormField something like this:

```
widgetTextField: TextFormField(
                  enabled: enable,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
                  controller: controllerNumClient,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  onFieldSubmitted: (valor) {
                    _findClient();
                  },
                ),
```

The second file is the first part of the view named **part1_create_cq.dart**, using the constructor like this, where **widgetTextField** is the identifier:

```
class CreateCQpart1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController dateFO;
  final VoidCallback methodFO;
  final TextEditingController dateFS;
  final VoidCallback methodFS;
  final Widget widgetDropdownCFDI;
  final TextEditingController widgetControllerMXN;
  final bool enable;
  final TextEditingController widgetControllerRefClientOC;
  final Widget widgetCheckBox;
  final TextEditingController widgetControllerMumClient;
  final VoidCallback methodFindClient;
  Widget widgetTextField;
  final VoidCallback showInfo;
  final VoidCallback methodCreateClient;
  final VoidCallback methodEditClient;
  final String nClient;
  final String client;
  final String rfc;
  final String person;
  CreateCQpart1({
    Key key,
    this.nClient,
    this.client,
    this.rfc,
    this.person,
    this.showInfo,
    this.dateFO,
    this.dateFS,
    this.widgetControllerMXN,
    this.widgetControllerRefClientOC,
    this.widgetCheckBox,
    this.methodFO,
    this.methodFS,
    this.widgetDropdownCFDI,
    this.widgetControllerMumClient,
    this.methodFindClient,
    this.enable,
    this.methodCreateClient,
    this.methodEditClient,
    this.widgetTextField,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<CreateCQpart1> createState() => _CreateCQpart1State();
}
```

and i put the widget like this:

```
Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                  width: 80,
                  child: Text(
                    'Number de client*:',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  )),
              Container(
                  height: 36, width: 120, child: this.widget.widgetTextField),
              SizedBox(
                width: 37,
                height: 37,
```

on the same, I have a button where i have this method to return a data from another file named **content_filter_client.dart** where i search fo the data for use and put into the widgetTextField on file **part1_create_cq.dart**, this is the method on **content_filter_client.dart**:

```
 onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
         numberClient =
            '${results[index].noClient}';
               });

      _sendBack(context);
            }),
```

and

```
void _sendBack(BuildContext context) {
    var infoSendBack = numberClient;

    Navigator.pop(context, infoSendBack);
  }
```

and the method on **part1_create_cq.dart** is:

```
void _navigateToSearchScreen(BuildContext context) async {
    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    final result = await Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FilterClient()));

    //after
    setState(() {
      widget.widgetTextField = result;
    });
  }
```

The error that comes from all of this is that it does not place the data in the TextFormField, and i got this error message on the debbugconsole

```
E/flutter ( 6324): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Widget' in type cast
E/flutter ( 6324): #0      _CreateCQpart1State._navigateToSearchScreen.<anonymous closure>
part1_create_cq.dart:486
E/flutter ( 6324): #1      State.setState
framework.dart:1088
E/flutter ( 6324): #2      _CreateCQpart1State._navigateToSearchScreen
part1_create_cq.dart:485
E/flutter ( 6324): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6324):
```

[ErrorImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3py0.png)

This question help me to do the method:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53861303/20532198

Is there a way to pass the data correctly by this method??? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through all of your code but seeing error and the last piece of code I can guess your callback is returning a string and you're trying to assign it to

> widgetTextField

which is a **Widget**, what you can do is either create a new TextFormField widget assign result value to it and then assign it to your widgetTextField, which i won't recommend instead you should make some changes in your code to update the string variable which can reflect it in your TextFormField.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, you think it could work if i manipulate the data on vars and then put it on the widget element at the principal view?? As an emergency alternative ?

Comment: if you need emergency alternative then just pass an updated text widget, otherwise you will have to change a lot of code.